# What does mounting a filesystem with user_xattr do?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

SELinux documentation for Debian says that `user_xattr` is not the same as extended attributes. So what is it?

Answer (score 13):

Mounting a filesystem with `user_xattr` enables support for extended user attributes. These are a specific type of extended attributes; from [`attr(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/attr.5.html):

> Extended user attributes may be assigned to files and directories for
>          storing arbitrary additional information such as the mime type,
>          character set or encoding of a file.  The access permissions for user
>          attributes are defined by the file permission bits: read permission
>          is required to retrieve the attribute value, and writer permission is
>          required to change it.

Other types of extended attributes are security attributes (used *e.g.* for SELinux), system attributes (ACLs etc.), and trusted attributes (restricted to `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`).

There's a matching `nouser_xattr` to explicitly disable extended user attributes.

Most of the filesystems which support extended user attributes enable them by default nowadays, so `user_xattr` is no longer necessary; the exception is ReiserFS. `ext2` and `ext3` used to require support to be enabled with this option, but that is no longer true (see [`xattr(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) for details).

Comment: So it only enables the use of `user.*` attributes? Can't I use those without this mount option?

Comment: @Melab in the past yes, but nowadays it's enabled by default (except on ReiserFS).

Comment: Then why do I see it on my smartphone? Also, explain `inline_xattr`.

Comment: And why does it enabke just `user.*`? What is different about `trusted.*`, `system.*`, and `security.*`?

Comment: Your smartphone is presumably using F2FS, which reports `user_xattr` explicitly even when it's enabled by default. `inline_xattr` is F2FS-specific and indicates the ability to store extended attributes in an inode. `user_xattr` only controls user attributes because that's what it's designed for; the other types of extended attributes are always enabled by default on systems which support them. The difference is that any user can write user attributes, whereas other xattrs have stricter access controls (and so less risk associated with enabling them).